# Tuple indices must be integers not tuple, matplot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, graph, tuples

I'm trying to code a program that will integrate a function using diferent ways (Euler, Runge...) and using the build-in function scipy.integrate.odeint.

Everything and I'm getting the right results but I also need to create a graph with the results and that's when everything goes wrong.
For the odeint function I can't draw the graph.
Here is my code and the ERROR, I hope someone will be able to help me.

```
def odeint(phi, t0tf, Y0, N):

    T6=numpy.zeros((N+1)) 
    T6[0]=t0tf[0]
    h=(t0tf[1]-t0tf[0])/N

    for i in range (N):
        T6[i+1]=T6[i]+h

    def f(t,x):
        return phi(x,t)

    Y6 = scipy.integrate.odeint(f,Y0,T6, full_output=True)

    return Y6

Y6 = edo.odeint(phi, t0tf, Y0, N)
T6Y6 = numpy.hstack([Y6])
print("Solutions Scipy :")
print()
print(T6Y6)
print()

mpl.figure("Courbes")
mpl.plot(Y6[0:N,0],Y6[0:N,1],color="yellow",label="Isoda")
mpl.show()
```

And the error is :

```
 mpl.plot(Y6[0:N,0],Y6[0:N,1],color="yellow",label="Isoda")

 TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Thanks in advance (PS: I'm french so my sentences might be kinda shaky)

Comment: Can you please include the full traceback and include enough information that we can copy-paste-run your example?

Answer (score 0):

`Y6` seems to be a tuple that you are calling in an incorrect way. It's difficult to point out exactly what is wrong since you didn't provide the data but the following example shows you how to call elements from a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

```
y = ((1,2,3,4,5),)
print('This one works: ',y[0][1:])
print(y[1:,0])
```

, the result is this:

```
This one works:  (2, 3, 4, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\armatita\stackoverflow\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(y[1:,0])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```